# JSON call not working with Session Package

Tags: json, struts2

I'm having a hell of a time trying to make a JSON call work within a Struts2 package that implements a session. Whenever I make the call, the appropriate execution method is invoked, but none of the getter methods are invoked. As such, no data is being returned to the page. Here's my Struts.xml

```
<package name="agreements" extends="default" namespace="/agreements">
      ...
</package>

<package name="new-wizard" extends="agreements, json-default" namespace="/new-wizard">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor-stack name="agreementsStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="scope">
                <param name="session">agreements, financialReportFirstReport, performanceReportFirstReport, tbvId, hasModification, tbvLoaded, subContractorGoals</param>
                <param name="key">partialAgreements</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="paramsPrepareParamsStack"/>
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>
    <default-interceptor-ref name="agreementsStack" />
...

    <action name="subContractorGoals" class="com.mycompany.webapp.action.AgreementsSubContractorWizardAction" method="subContractorGoals">
        <result type="json">
            <param name="includeProperties">subContractorGoals.*</param>
        </result>
    </action>
</package>
```

And this is my javascript:

```
var goals = null;
$.ajax({
                async: false,
                type:'GET',
                dataType:'json',
                url:"../new-wizard/subContractorGoals",
                success:function(data) {
                    console.log("dataStringify = " + JSON.stringify(data));

                    goals = data.subContractorGoals;
                }
            });
```

The output to my console is always the same - {}. I'm getting back an object, but it's empty. What's really confusing to me is that if I take that exact same action and place it in another package, it works.

```
<package name="json" extends="default, json-default" namespace="/json">
    <action name="subContractorGoals" class="com.mycompany.webapp.action.AgreementsSubContractorWizardAction" method="subContractorGoals">
        <result type="json">
            <param name="includeProperties">subContractorGoals.*</param>
        </result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Java:

```
@SkipValidation
public String subContractorGoals()
{
    try
    {
        this.subContractorGoals = new HashMap<String, Double>();
                    this.subContractorGoals.put("test", 1.0);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ERROR;
}
```

and my result from the previous javascript (package name changed to `/json` of course) is `{"subContractorGoals":{"test":"1.0"}}`

I'm really at a loss as to what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of the Interceptors in your Stack:

```
<interceptor-stack name="agreementsStack">

    <interceptor-ref name="paramsPrepareParamsStack"/>

    <interceptor-ref name="scope">
        <param name="session">agreements, financialReportFirstReport, 
                              performanceReportFirstReport, tbvId, 
                              hasModification, tbvLoaded, subContractorGoals
        </param>
        <param name="key">partialAgreements</param>
    </interceptor-ref>

</interceptor-stack>
```